# Name mangling in CUDA and C++

Tags: c++, cuda, nvcc, name-mangling, pgi

My C++ project `main.cpp`, compiled with `pgcpp` from PGI, calls a function `cuda()` containing CUDA code in a separate file `cuda.cu`, compiled with `nvcc`. Unless I wrap the `cuda()` function with `extern "C"` in the function declaration and the common header file, I get linking errors (undefined references).

Without `extern "C"` (symbol name mismatch => undefined reference):

```
$ nm main.o | grep -y cuda
U cuda__FPfPiT2iN32
$ nm cuda.o | grep -y cuda
T _Z13cudaPfPiS0_iS0_S0_S0_
```

With `extern "C"` (symbol name match => linking works fine):

```
$ nm main.o | grep -y cuda
U cuda
$ nm cuda.o | grep -y cuda
T cuda
```

It was my impression that `nvcc` used the host C++ compiler for host code, and that it would therefore mangle symbol names as in C++? What am I doing wrong then?

EDIT: Could this be due to the fact that `nvcc` actually uses the GNU compiler `gcc` for host code, and that this compiler mangles names differently than `pgcpp`?

EDIT2: My system has pgcpp 14.9, gcc 4.4.7, nvcc/CUDA 6.5

Comment: nvcc in CUDA 6.5 and prior will use the host gnu compiler.  PGI tools have both a PGI "native" toolchain and a PGI gnu-compatible toolchain.  You can either switch to the PGI gnu-compatible toolchain (i.e. use `pgc++` instead of `pgcpp`), or you can switch to CUDA 7 which can use the PGI toolchain as your host compiler.  You may want to study the [PGI documentation](https://www.pgroup.com/support/new_rel.htm).

Comment: Indeed this was my first reflex. The PGI User Guide does not indicate any difference between `pgc++` and `pgcpp`. The symbol names are indeed mangled identically when compiling the pure C++ code with `pgc++` instead of `pgcpp`. Thanks!

Comment: Regarding this statement: "The PGI User Guide does not indicate any difference between pgc++ and pgcpp",  try looking at page **xv** of the [PGI user guide](https://www.pgroup.com/doc/pgiug.pdf).

Comment: You are correct. I was given the 2014 version of the user guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nvcc` uses (on linux) the host gcc/g++ (gnu) toolchain, by default.

PGI offers two slightly different toolchains for compiling C++ code.  One toolchain is invoked using the `pgcpp` tool.  This toolchain is *not* gnu-compatible, and will not necessarily produce gnu-compatible name-mangling.  The other toolchain is invoked using the `pgc++` tool, and it is advertised as gnu-compatible, and should produce gnu-compatible name mangling.

Linking problems of this type between objects produced by `nvcc` and PGI tools should be resolved by using the `pgc++` tool.

As an aside, with CUDA 7 it is now possible to use the PGI compiler (`pgc++`) as the host compiler for `nvcc`.  However this is not the crux of the issue here, although switching to that host compiler would fix the linking issue in a similar fashion.

Differences between `pgcpp` and `pgc++` are referred to in current versions of the [PGI users guide](https://www.pgroup.com/doc/pgiug.pdf) (e.g. page xv) and the [PGI 2015 release notes](https://www.pgroup.com/support/new_rel.htm):

> PGI 2015 Features and Performance
>
> •PGI C++ Compiler
>
> ◦PGC++ (pgc++) is now default on Linux and OS X. Features include GNU compatible name mangling and language features supporting g++ versions 4.2-4.8.
>
> ...
>
> ◦pgc++ is also now supported as an NVCC host compiler on Linux

Note that `pgc++` is now (2015) considered "default" and `pgcpp` is listed as "deprecated."